# Git-server repository to be accessed with Cygwin+SSH

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

I have a Windows server machine on which I am hosting a repository. I created a bare repository on it which is accessible using file protocol with the following command.

```
git clone //my-server/git/test.git
```

This all works fine for me and the repository clones successfully on my local machine.

Now I have to access this repository through **ssh**. For this, I have installed **Cygwin** on the server and have configured a ssh-host using the `ssh-host-config` command. I have also added a local windows user to **/etc/passwd**.

I can successfully log into the server using **ssh** and play with the server from my local machine.

However, we I try the command `git clone ssh://my-server/git/test.git`. I am presented with the following error on the command prompt.

```
fatal: '/git/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I even tried installing Cygwin's Git but that didn't help either. I am not sure exactly where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can think of it your SSH URL is not right.

Try git clone ssh://user@server/git/test.git or git clone user@server:git/git.test.

For more details refer [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols/#The-SSH-Protocol).